# My userform will not return any results idatabaserow error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a return on a search function however get a 1004 runtime error on the following formula. The error seems to be along the idatabase row which will be a mix of text, numbers and dates

```vb
Sub SearchData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim shDatabase As Worksheet 'Database Sheet
    Dim shSearchData As Worksheet 'SearchData Sheet
    
    Dim icolumn As Integer 'To hold  the selected column number in database sheet
    Dim iDatabaseRow As Long 'To store the last non blank row number available in Database sheet
    Dim iSearchRow As Long ' To hold the last non blacnk row number in SearchData sheet
    
    Dim sColumn As String 'To store the column selection
    Dim sValue As String 'To hold the search text value
    
    Set shDatabase = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    Set shSearchData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SearchData")
    
    ' === Error here ===
    iDatabaseRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(X1Up).row
    sColumn = frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.Value    
    sValue = frmForm.txtSearch.Value
    
    icolumn = AApplication.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(sColumn), shDatabase.Range("A1:K1"), 0)
    
    'Remove filter from Database worksheet
    If shDatabase.FilterMode = True Then
        shDatabase.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    'Apply Filter on Database worksheet
    If frmForm.cmbSearchColumn.Value = "PO" Then
        shDatabase.Range("A1:K" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=icolumn, Criteria1:=sValue
    Else
        shDatabase.Range("A1:K" & iDatabaseRow).AutoFilter Field:=icolumn, Criteria1:="*" & sValue & "*"
    End If
    
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, shDatabase.Range("C:C")) >= 2 Then
        'Code to remove the previous data from search data worksheet
        shSearchData.Cells.Clear
        shDatabase.AutoFilter.Range.Copy.shSearchData.Range ("A1")
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        iSearchRow = shSearchData.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        
        frmForm.lstDatabase.Column = 10
        frmForm.lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "60,60,75,40,60,45,55,70,70,70,70"
        
        If iSearch > 1 Then
            frmForm.lstDatabase.RowSource = "SearchData!A2:K" & iSearchRow
            MsgBox "Records Found"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No Record Found"
    End If
    
    shDatabase.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I was hoping it would return a search result from the database

Comment: `X1Up` => `xlUp`.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` to avoid such errors. Funfact (okay, not so funny) : Searching for `X1Up` on SO gives 180 hits!

Comment: Another 60 with `x1Down`.